# How to show Registrant Name in WHOIS lookup?

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration, whois, gdpr

I have purchased a domain name (`anishghosh.me`) from `bigrock.com` but when I'm doing a WHOIS lookup on the domain the registrant name is not showing in that information. How can I show my name as the registrant in the WHOIS lookup?

Comment: Which registrar do you use?

Comment: bigrock.com is the registrar

Comment: You need to provide authorization for them to release your details publicly https://manage.bigrock.in/kb/answer/2957

Answer (score 6):

## Why do the details not show by default

This is because of the GDPR, which brought in a lot of personal data protections, and resulted in a large amount of changes to WHOIS, in order to try to make it compliant.

## How do I get my details shown

If you want your details to show, you need to provide authorization for this, which you can find more information about [here](https://manage.bigrock.in/kb/answer/2957), and information about how to provide the authorization [here](https://manage.bigrock.in/kb/answer/2958).

Comment: gdpr protection is not showing in my control panel

Comment: Do you have an EU address linked to the domain?

Comment: This all depends on the domain and the TLD in fact. Not having this information makes it difficult to reply.

Comment: The registrars I have seen have applied changes across the board, are there ones which kept EU contacts live for certain TLDs

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The domain (and TLD) are mentioned in the question.

Comment: Performing a WHOIS lookup on the domain in question, does appear to return partial details (but only the "Organization", "State/Province" and "Country" are reported and "Organization" is "N/A"). And the registrant appears to be outside the EEA, so this may not be a GDPR thing after all (although if "any" contact is within the EEA then GDPR is still applied). I don't think this is a TLD (registry) thing, since I also have a `.me` domain, which shows considerably more information than what is being reported here.

Comment: @DocRoot it is a registry change as it is a registry whois server reply (from `whois.nic.me`). The results may be different between an organization and an individual as registrant.

Comment: It'd make sense if registries were being conservative with who they redact details for, €20 million is quite a persuasive fine

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes, you are right. I'd overlooked that the _whois_ tool I use is set to automatically perform a secondary lookup on the "Registrar WHOIS Server" field (on the _thin_ record returned from the Registry whois server) which - for my domain - returned the additional information. In the OPs case, the "secondary lookup" does appear to return anything.

Comment: @DocRoot this 2 steps whois is mostly in gTLDs.... ccTLDs do not mandate their registrar to run a whois server at all...

Comment: TYPO CORRECTION: "In the OPs case, the "secondary lookup" does **not** appear to return anything." _tssh_.